# Orientation of Magnets in Paramagnetic Substances

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

We know that electrons can act as magnets and are responsible for the properties of para, diamagnetism, etc.

In particular, paramagnetic and ferromagnetic materials are permanent magnets due to the existence of unpaired electrons.

Ferromagnetic and Anti-Ferromagnetic materials contain electrons whose magnetic moments are "aligned" either to cancel each other out or are all in the same direction.

However, when it comes to paramagnetism, we say that the magnetic moments of electrons in the absence of an external field are "random". Why is this the case?

From what I know, the magnetic moment of an electron arises due to its spin. An electron can have either +1/2 or -1/2 spin. Doesn't this imply that there are only two ways an electron's magnetic moment can be arranged? If the random arrangement we're referring to is just a random order of +1/2 and -1/2 electrons, doesn't this definition overlap with that of "ferri-magnetic" substances?

Comment: Sorry, my (now deleted) answer was about diamagnetism.  In ferromagnetism, the electron spins are aligned in domains by a cooperative quantum interactions.  In paramagnetism, the spins were randomly oriented, as you said, because there is no preferred direction until a magnetic field is applied.

Comment: But by definition of spin, there are only two possible arrangements right? My question was what exactly does "having no preferred direction" mean, since there are only two possible "directions" of spin from how we defined it